# How to make a mjpeg stream from pixelarray

Tags: c++, stream, raspberry-pi, rtsp, mjpeg

I want to make a Raspi based networkcamera but WITHOUT the original raspi Camera. I have a camera that gives me single frames which I store in a 2d array. 1 Byte/Pixel because it is grayscale.

What are the steps I have to do to convert it to a Stream that I can watch via HTTP request or Socket Stream or rtsp.

How do I need to convert the single Frames into something that I can stream via Network?

Do I take a single frame and convert it to jpeg (or mjpeg) or something different?

Programming language is C or C++ nothing else.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: OpenCV and Video4Linux for the capture.  I have cheated this a bit by simply saving the images to jpeg (files) and then using a web-server to serve them with embedded javascript to refresh.

Comment: which framerate do you get out of this?